# Two-dimensional array, modified one field at a time

Tags: javascript, memory-optimization

Title says it all. I'm basically initializing a two-dimensional array and changing the fields one at a time.

It might be a good idea to do this OO.
A `Grid` class seems right, perhaps as a subclass of `Array`. So far I haven't been able to successfully port it. Pointers would probably be a good idea as well.

Note this is kind of a sandbox project at the moment. I'm a novice in JS and trying to wrap my head around how I can handle data efficiently (particularly memory efficient, CPU is not as relevant).

Partial reviews are also welcome.

```
Array.initialize = function(iRows, iColumns, cInit) {
    var array = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < iRows; ++i) {
        var columns = [];
        for (var j = 0; j < iColumns; ++j) {
            columns[j] = initial;
        }
       array[i] = columns;
    }
  return array;
}

Array.shoot = function(row, column, array) {
  array[row][column] = "H";
  return array;
}

var myGrid = Array.initialize(12, 12, "U");
myGrid = Array.shoot(5, 5, myGrid);
myGrid = Array.shoot(0, 4, myGrid);

console.log(myGrid);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A few things:

- Someone's getting a head-start on [Battleship](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5231/may-2015-community-challenge), eh? :)
- Don't modify native objects/prototypes. `Array` is the native JavaScript array constructor (a.k.a. "class"), and you're adding `initialize` and `shoot` methods to it. Don't. 
  Well, ok, you *can* extend native objects, but it's more hygienic to leave it alone. And in this case the methods you're adding are super-specific to your task, and not generic functionality, so that's a double "don't".
- I'm pretty sure you have a bug: `cInit` isn't used for anything, but instead you have an previously undeclared (and therefor `undefined`) variable called `initial`. I'm guessing they were supposed to be one and the same.

Now, in terms of memory efficiency: Don't worry about it. JavaScript has automatic memory management and garbage collection, but it's buried deep in the runtime, so it's not something you can fiddle with. It also has dynamic typing, so it's kinda hard to even guess at memory consumption at times. For instance, the number `32` is 8 bytes long, since all numbers are 64-bit IEEE floating point values, yet `32 == "32"` happens to be true due to dynamic typing/type-coercion. So the string `"32"` is for some purposes it's the same number, but it's probably only 2-3 bytes long. Maybe? I don't know. Because behind the scenes, all JS runtimes do a ton of voodoo, so in the end it's really hard to tell what's going on. Besides the runtime's own memory consumption is probably way beyond whatever data you're handling. The runtime might well trade memory for speed somewhere. And another runtime might do the opposite, but they'll both run your code the same.

Point is, memory just isn't a thing you really *can* worry about in JavaScript the same way you can worry about it in other languages. At least not on the same low level. Of course you can still run out of memory and things like that, but you'd have to try pretty hard. Especially with a simple little 2D array.

Aside: Don't bother with Hungarian notation either. Well, again, you *can*, but it's a lot of busywork when there's dynamic typing and type-coercion. You have parameters like `iRows`, which, yeah, should be an integer, but as mentioned all integers are just the `Number` type - which is really a float. And you could also pass in a numeric string and have it work. So it just gets confusing in a hurry.

Of course, you still want *efficient* data structures, but since the idea here is to construct a 2D array, well, you're probably best off using... a 2D array. So again, don't worry too much.

As for the code, you have the basics well in hand. As mentioned, you shouldn't be appending functions to the native `Array` constructor, but otherwise it's fine. Fixing that little thing you get:

```
function createArray(rows, columns, initialValue) {
  var array = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
    var columns = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < columns; ++j) {
      columns[j] = initialValue;
    }
    array[i] = columns;
  }
  return array;
}

function shoot(row, column, array) {
  array[row][column] = "H";
  return array;
}
```

Still, I'd use `push` to append stuff to an array, rather than assigning things to an index.

But you said you might want a more OO-style implementation. However, sub-classing `Array` would be tricky. Especially as there are no "classes" in JavaScript, per se. It's easier to go with object composition; make your own constructor, and have your array be a property (aka member, aka instance variable) on the instances that constructor creates.

So let's make a `Grid` constructor and let's give it a `shoot` method:

```
function Grid(rows, columns) {
  var r, c, row;
  this.cells = []; // instance variable
  for(r = 0 ; r < rows ; r++) {
    row = [];
    for(c = 0 ; c < columns ; c++) {
      row.push("U");
    }
    this.cells.push(row);
  }
}

Grid.prototype.shoot = function (row, column) {
  this.cells[row][column] = "H";
};
```

Now, much like before, you can say:

```
var grid = new Grid(12, 12);
grid.shoot(5, 5);
grid.shoot(0, 4);

console.log(grid.cells); // notice you still have access to the "raw" array
```

Of course, you may want to do some bounds-checking in `shoot` to make sure the coordinates make sense, but otherwise... yeah, that's pretty much it.

Comment: There were a couple of things I was sure should be done better and you covered all of them, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, a two-dimensional array optimzed for size would be a one-dimensional (native) array with a mapping of row/col addressing to (simple) index access. Demo:

```
//function print(x) {WScript.Echo(x);} // for windows/jscript

function assert(b, m) {
    if (!b) {
        print("bingo: " + m);
    }
}

function Arr2D(rs, cs, iv) {
    this.rs = rs;
    this.cs = cs;
    this.rc = this.rs + "x" + this.cs;
    this.d = Array(rs * cs);
    for (var i = 0; i < this.d.length; ++i) {
        this.d[i] = iv;
    }

    this.dump = function() {
        print(this.rc + ": [" + this.d.join(",") + "]");
    };

    this.shoot = function(r, c) {
        assert(r >= 0 && r < this.rs, "row index " + r + " out of range " + this.rc);
        assert(c >= 0 && c < this.cs, "col index " + c + " out of range " + this.rc);
        this.d[r * cs + c] = "H";
    };
}

var a2d = new Arr2D(2, 3, 6);
a2d.dump();
a2d.shoot(0, 0);
a2d.shoot(1, 2);
a2d.shoot(1, 0);
a2d.shoot(0, 2);
a2d.dump();

a2d.shoot(2, -1);
```

output:

```
cscript 88914.js
2x3: [6,6,6,6,6,6]
2x3: [H,6,H,H,6,H]
bingo: row index 2 out of range 2x3
bingo: col index -1 out of range 2x3
```

or:

```
Rhino 1.7 release 5 PRERELEASE 2013 07 16
js> load("88914.js");
2x3: [6,6,6,6,6,6]
2x3: [H,6,H,H,6,H]
bingo: row index 2 out of range 2x3
bingo: col index -1 out of range 2x3
js> quit()
```